# how to implement page control in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

since i am developing a project on Exchange trade fund and in its first page layout
we are developing labels and we want that  on clicking on that labels page related to that
label may appear on another vertical field manager on the same screen and on that very screen i want page control so that on tracking wheel we may obtain the next page following that page

thanking you

Comment: It would have been better to just edit your original question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053723/how-to-implement-page-control-in-blackberry than to create a new one

Answer (score 0):

You can capture trackwheel (e.g.  trackwheelClick, trackwheelRoll) events and update the textual contents of the page appropriately.

Just implement these functions as a part of your mainscreen class.